# Import export service - LDAP error

Tags: ldap, importexportservice

When we connect to import-export service to perform export / import even for one component, the process fails and the error that is logged in the event viewer is: **The server cannot handle directory requests.**

> Component: LdapAuthenticationHttpModule Errorcode: 0  User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> StackTrace Information Details:    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ErrorChecking.CheckAndSetLdapError(Int32
>   error)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapSessionOptions.FastConcurrentBind()
>   at
>   Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.GetLdapAutenticationConnection(Boolean
>   forceStandardBind)    at
>   Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.AuthenticateUser(String userName,
>   String password)    at
>   Tridion.Security.Web.LdapAuthenticationHttpModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

We have 6 CM servers out of which we are seeing above error only for content porter and webdav in 3 CM servers and other 3 CM servers are working fine.

If we access the CME, it works fine with Ldap authentication.

We compared those working vs non-working servers however did not find any difference. Also ErrorCode is 0 for LdapAuthenticationModule which indicates success so I am not sure what could be the issue.

Has anybody faced similar issue? or If you have any pointers on things to look for then please share.

Any help is appreciated?

**Update 1:** We found one thing, the error for Ldap is happening for only few users including MTS user and not all users.

Comment: What are the security settings in IIS on ImportExportService virual folder?

Comment: It is set for anonymous authentication as suggested by Tridion documentation.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to grant rwx to IUSR on ImportExportService virual folder.

IUSR is the default user for anonymous login on IIS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, the system that are working fine also have the same permission as permission set on non-working system. So this doesn't seems to be the solution. Anyways, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace suggests there is a problem with connecting to the LDAP server. In particular, the LDAP authentication module is trying to do a so-called "Fast Concurrent Bind" on the LDAP server which fails with "The server cannot handle LDAP requests".  Fast Concurrent Bind is a feature implemented by Active Directory. The LDAP auth module uses that feature if advertised by the LDAP server (for performance reasons).

I don't know why you get the problem only on some of your CM server and only for specific operation, but I would suggest to check your LDAP Server logs.

Comment: We have already worked with our networking team to trace the LDAP logs however we did not find anything useful.

Comment: Do you have special characters in the (search) account names? I vaguely remember there were Fast Concurrent Bind issues in that case. Anyways, I suggest to contact SDL Customer Support for this issue.